# Using Java 8 Streams' Collectors to increment value based of existing key/value pair

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Suppose there is a `List<Object>` and that `Object` contains two methods: `getUserId` and `getPoints`.

Consider that `List<Object>` contains three objects, and they contain the following data:

```
userId A; 3 points
userId A; 5 points
userId B; 1 point
```

After collecting this properly, I am expecting to have a `Map<String, Integer>` that would look like this:

```
A: 8,
B: 1
```

I am attempting this using Java's 8 functional interfaces, the streams, because I only need the final result and I do not have nor need any of these mappings in between. I am willing to modify this if there is no other way. 
I first came up with this:

```
this.service.getListObject()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getUserId, Object::getPoints));
```

However, this has shown insufficient because it will always replace the key with the newest value, thus producing:

```
A: 5,
B: 1
```

How can I tweak the last bits from the `Collectors.toMap()` to automatically increment its value according to the value already stored in the map, so that I produce the result above?

Comment: Actually, `Collectors.toMap` will throw an exception if the keys are not unique; it will not replace it with newest value.

Comment: I don't think this has happened in my last attempt to execute the program. Ultimately, it has not updated the values properly but no exceptions were thrown and I guarantee that there are duplicate keys for this.

Comment: Perhaps, you did specify a merge function like `(a,b)->b` rather than omitting it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) together with [`Collectors.summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) as a downstream collector:

```
this.service.getListObject()
    .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Object::getUserId, Collectors.summingInt(Object::getPoints)));
```

Answer (score 4):

To correct the implementation that you had started off, you need a merge function as:

```
...stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObject::getUserId, 
                    CustomObject::getPoints, Integer::sum)); // <--- summing value here
```

which eventually can be represented with a combination of `groupingBy` and `summingInt` as well.